# Interpretation of vector mesons in QCD

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, representation-theory, symmetry-breaking, mesons

It is well-known that scalar mesons are interpreted as pseudogoldstone bosons which is connected with spontaneous broken $SU(3) \times SU(3)$ symmetry to $SU(3) \times SU(3) / SU(3)_{chiral}$.

Is there similar explanation for vector mesons? I understand that broken symmetry corresponds to existense of particles with spin zero, but I expect that vector mesons can also be explained through something like that, because they correspond to irreducible representation of $SU(3)$ group (as well as scalar mesons).

Comment: Since physicists are very sloppy with this - do you mean $\otimes$ or $\times$, i.e. the tensor product or the direct product of groups? (I heavily suspect it is $\times$)

Comment: A good reference for this (maybe not the best, just the one I know about) is in the introductory chapter of Manohar and Wise's textbook on heavy quark physics. Granted, this is presented as a review for someone who's familiar with it (which I am not), and I've been hoping to find a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : I meaned direct product (I thought that $\otimes$ denotes direct product).

Comment: @jwimberley : Where exactly can I find information about vector mesons in this chapter?

Comment: @AndrewMcAddams You can't, because I was wrong! Sorry for the red herring. A later chapter does talk about the mass splitting between the spin 1 D* and B* mesons relative to the spin 0 D and B mesons, which is derived in the heavy quark limit and isn't general. I'd confused this with the introductory section 1.4, which just covers chiral symmetry breaking and the masses of spin-0 mesons.

Answer (score 1):

A note on your question: the chiral *SU(3)×SU(3)* is dynamically broken by QCD to just the flavor ("eightfold way") *SU(3)*. Your coset expression would be meaningful if the subscript were "vector" not "chiral", and it could serve as a summary of the 8 SSBroken axial generators of the full chiral starting group, not the surviving ones. So you might be asking for an explanation of the non-existent.

Indeed, 8 pseudoscalar mesons are the pseudogoldstone bosons corresponding to these 8 broken generators. And, indeed, glorious speculation has been proffered on vector mesons being, effectively, [SSB gauge fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_meson_dominance#VMD_and_Hidden_Local_Symmetry) notably in the reference by [Bando, Kugo, et al](http://ptp.oxfordjournals.org/content/73/6/1541.full.pdf).

However, consider that any *other mesons*, scalars, tensors, etc., *do not admit of such interpretations*. If you are seeking a grand reductionist picture for all mesons in chiral symmetry breaking, it appears to be lacking---so far!